# Convert NSString to UTF8String?

Tags: ios, utf-8, nsstring, format

Currently I am download data from a server and I have this line to get that NSData into a NSString.

```
NSString *txt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

How would I go from here to convert that NSString into a UTF8 string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSData *utf8Data = [txt dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `NSASCIIStringEncoding` to `NSUTF8StringEncoding` .

I ran a quick test now with some dummy data and seemed to work fine with just that one line.